# Language design (Exceptions): Why `try`?

Tags: exception, programming-languages, language-design

In the languages where I've seen exceptions (C++, Java, Javascript, Python, PHP, ...), I always see `try`, or something similar, to mark the scope of a `catch`. I wonder if it's necessary. What are the design issues with NOT having `try` blocks?

For example, take this:

```
try{
    try{
        do_something_dangerous0();
    }catch (SomeProblem p){
        handle(p);
    }
    try{
        do_something_dangerous1();
    }catch (SomeProblem p){
        handle(p);
    }
}catch (SomeOtherProblem p){
    handle(p);
}
```

I imagine this as an alternative.

```
do_something_dangerous0();

catch (SomeProblem p){
    handle(p);
}

do_something_dangerous1();

catch (SomeProblem p){
    //catches from only the second unless the first also threw
    handle(p);
}

catch (SomeOtherProblem p){
    //catches from either, because no other block up there would
    handle(p);
}
```

If you want to avoid a block catching "too much", you can make a new scope:

```
do_something_dangerous2();

{
    do_something_dangerous3();

    catch (SomeProblem p){
        //does not catch from do_something_dangerous2()
        //because if that throws, it won't reach in here
        handle(p);
    }
}

catch (SomeProblem p){
    handle(p);
}

catch (SomeOtherProblem p){
    handle(p);
}
```

(My answer for why this won't work for languages like C++ and Java, at least, is posted as an answer below, but I don't have an answer for dynamic languages.)

Comment: In the general case you need to precisely delimit the start and end of the exception handling range.  One could use a "lonesome" `{}` range for that, but it wouldn't really change anything, and would be less clear.

Comment: (I did once work on a system that used BEGIN/NIGEB macros to delimit the exception handling range, but the overall structure was virtually identical to try/catch/finally.  The function determines the syntax, not the other way around.)

Comment: Didn't I address that with 'If you want to avoid a block catching "too much"...'?

Comment: Yes, but the structure is still just as complicated and less clear (because it lacks the "try" sentinel).  All you really do is save 3 bytes being typed.

Comment: In that particular case, you WANT the `try` block, because you are trying to do something that _semantically_ requires a scope deeper than the one you're currently in. And it doesn't have to be less clear (if it's big enough to impact clarity, you should comment the block anyway). I'm asking about the problems with making the deeper scope optional in the cases where it's not SEMANTICALLY required (e.g. catch for whole function).

Comment: So then you save 5 characters?  At the expense of a more irregular grammar?

Comment: I am asking a question about language design, because I am interested in language design. If you want to say that this necessitates a more irregular grammar, great, expand that and post it as an answer.

Comment: Certainly you can change the grammar to just about anything.  (Have you ever heard of the language Whitespace?)  But the current "standard" is pretty much the minimal design.  As I said, I once worked on a system where we developed an EH mechanism using (PL/S) macros.  The full set was BEGIN/ABEXIT/EXIT/NIBEB, where BEGIN was `try`, ABEXIT was `catch`, EXIT was `finally`, and NIBEB the closing bracket.  (And, in fact, it eventually incorporated a facility similar to "try with resource".)  This is so much similar to the familiar Java model that one assumes it's a fundamental thing.

Comment: Maybe you haven't stated a question.  You can change the grammar all you want, but the fundamental requirements remain.  In particular, there must be some way to delineate an exception handling range.  (And a "complete" implementation would likely include a better way to express the "try with resource" concept.)

Comment: If you're determined to study this you should read [Goodenough](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~bec/courses/csci5535-s09/reading/goodenough-exceptions.pdf).

Comment: My question is, "What are the design issues with NOT having try blocks?". My alternative, as shown by my first example, was to use the immediate outer scope of the `catch` _to determine what it can catch_. You are arguing that there must be a way _to determine what it can catch_, and therefore `try` is necessary. (And thanks for the link.)

Comment: Yes, you can redefine a language like that.  You can also eliminate the `if` statement and replace it with `while/break`.  Lots of things you can do.  But a computer language should be as easy to read and understand as possible, and making one search for the opening `{` for a catch statement will not be progress in that direction.

Comment: Then that is _an issue_ and that is the kind of *answer* I am looking for.

Comment: You asked "What are the design issues with NOT having try blocks?"  You must have a "block" of some sort to define the handler range.  Whether you call it "try" or "hippopotamus" is a design decision (but I'd favor "try", of the two).

Comment: Again, the alternative I gave is precisely to use the enclosing scope of the catch, ending at the catch itself, to determine the handler range, rather than an explicit block. This was demonstrated in the two examples I gave, as well as my partial answer. The "necessary" issue was already addressed in my original proposal, and that solution in fact causes scope problems for _static_ languages, as I point out in my answer. You are repeatedly pointing out something that was already addressed.

Comment: So you're calling it a "hippopotamus".  To what advantage?

Answer (score 4):

It wouldn't work for languages which require variable declarations, at least.

Any statement in the `try` block may fail to fully execute, including declarations and initializations of variables. In languages with block scoping, especially languages that require variable declarations like C++, Objective C, and Java, the `catch` block does not share the scope of the `try` block, so it is not allowed to access the `try`'s local variables. The `try`-less system would break scoping rules.

For example, this is valid C++ code.

```
try{
    int x = some_func();
    int y = some_other_func();
}catch(SomeException){
    //...
}
```

If this were converted to,

```
int x = some_func();
int y = some_other_func();

catch(SomeException){
    //...
}
```

then, under the brace scoping rules, `x` and `y` are in-scope for the catch block, even though they might not be declared/initialized yet.

You can change the scoping rules so that the `catch` won't see those variable declarations, but that's a major complication of a very simple and pervasive rule to save on about seven characters (`try{\n` `}\n`). You can make it so that you can't do variable declarations immediately outside the scope of a `catch`, but then you can't do much without something like `try` blocks anyway. You can require all variables in a scope to be declared before running anything that can throw (similar to old C), but that takes away some freedom in structuring code and makes it harder to read.